# How to set up VPN connection in our Android Application

Tags: android

I am working an an Android project to set up a PPTP and L2TP VPN connection . I searching on this for almost two days and I understood that,We have to customize the Android SDK to make it functioning. But is it possible ? If possible ...how?

If we are customizing the SDK,it will work only that handset. I want a portable app.
Is there any other way to make it..... Plz reply any one

Thanx in advance

heyjii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the viewers

A new VPN client API is included in android 4.0. Hope it will help.

Comment: what do u mean by a new VPN client API is ..........can u illustrate it more since I need it so urgent to implement an L2TP VPN for Android.